# blk_get_request crashes when used on unpartiotioned block device

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

```
struct block_device *bdev = lookup_bdev("/dev/sdc");
struct request_queue *rq = bdev_get_queue(bdev);
req = blk_get_request(rq, READ, __GFP_RECLAIM);
```

above code works fine when I have partition on /dev/sdc but crashes when that partition is not there.

Strangely if I delete partition this code works without crash. until I restart machine.

```
[ 2238.666563] Hi. /dev/sdc
[ 2238.666591] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 00000000000003e0
[ 2238.666600] IP: [<ffffffffa06e7029>] local_block_execute+0x29/0xe6 [inquiry]
[ 2238.666610] PGD 80000000b6a80067 PUD b5bb7067 PMD 0
[ 2238.666616] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP
```

Comment: If it's crashing, you are probably using a return value without checking it. For example, the value returned from `lookup_bdev()` in the `bdev` variable might be an error code encoded as a pointer. Use `IS_ERR(bdev)` to check for that. If `IS_ERR(bdev)` is true, use `PTR_ERR(bdev)` to get the error value.

Comment: Let me check that. but interesting question here is why this different behavior in these two cases?